# pst-asr and syllabic structure

Tags: pstricks, linguistics, pst-asr

I've spent most of the current day trying to figure out how to use `pst-asr` with building syllabic configurations of complex (i.e., polysyllabic) words, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. What I need to do is the following:

[image]

As usual, any kind of help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I did it! Here's the code, in case someone needs it:

```
documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr,graphicx}
\tiershortcuts

\begin{document}

\newtier{nuclear,rhyme,coda,onset}
\psset{xgap=2.5em,yunit=2em,
phB=-1,nuclear=.9 (lg),coda=1.2 (dg),rhyme=2.3 (hy),
onset=4 (tg),syB=3.5}
\DefList{\onsetpos{1.5},\nuclearpos{1.5},\rhymepos{1.5}, \nuclearposs{4}, \rhymeposs{4}}

\asr pj{\textepsilon}|
\@(\nuclearpos,nuclear){N}
\-(2,ts)
\-(1,ts)
\@(\rhymepos,rhyme){R}
 \-(\nuclearpos,nuclear)
\@(1.5,sy){$\sigma$}
   \-(\onsetpos,onset)
    \-(0,ts)
  \-(\rhymepos,rhyme) |
de |
\@(\nuclearposs,nuclear){N}
 \-(4,ts)
\@(\rhymeposs,rhyme){R}
  \-(\nuclearposs,nuclear)
 \@(4,sy){$\sigma$}
  \-(\rhymeposs,rhyme)
  \-(3,ts)
\endasr

\end{document}
```

In case you need to do some sort of assimilation process, here's my solution:

```
\asr sbal |
\@(\nuclearpos,nuclear){N}
\-(2,ts)
\@(\rhymepos,rhyme){R}
\-(\nuclearpos,nuclear)
\@(2,sy){$\sigma$}
  \-(\onsetpos,onset)
    \-(1,ts)
        \-(0,ts)
  \-(\rhymepos,rhyme)
\@(1,feature){\feat{+voice}}
  \-(1,ph)
  \-[style=dotted](0,ph)
\@(\rhymepos,rhyme){R}
  \-(3,ts) |
lo |
\@(\nuclearposs,nuclear){N}
\-(5,ts)
\@(\rhymeposs,rhyme){R}
  \-(\nuclearposs,nuclear)
\@(5,sy){$\sigma$}
  \-(\rhymeposs,rhyme)
  \-(4,ts)
 \endasr
```

Comment: it's much more helpful to post a complete document than just the code fragment. (In both questions and answers...)

Comment: @Alan Munn: Ok, I'm on it!